problem during calls using the micro with wireless headphones
im using the zone vibe 125 wireless headphones and SO ubuntu 24.04.I use the dongle (for better quality audio) but when im in a call (or using the micro) the audio decrease the quality of the sounds (thats bc the audio profile changes). I tried to modify the profile to A2DP, but my micro doesnt work with that profile, have the same problem with bluetooth. Any idea about how to solve this ?

When you say 'micro' i'm assuming you mean 'microphone'.
When using a bluetooth headset with the microphone active, the bandwidth has to be shared with the headphone and the microphone, making the audio quality much worse. If you want to alway have high quality audio on your headphone when on a call, you'll want to use a dedicated microphone.
I've been having issues where my bluetooth headset auto switches profiles, even when using a dedicated microphone. I've found the following two posts but haven't yet done what they say, but you may find it useful if you come across the same issue:
Stop application/pulse audio changing Bluetooth Profile when joining a call
Disable Auto switch of bluetooth device profiles (specifically input), when apps request it, in pipewire and ubuntu 23.04
